# Rearrangeable DIVs in javascript (jQuery plugins)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone knows how i can implement re-arrangable divs (Drag the divs around on the page, but divs should not be overlapped, something like igoogle widgets). I was trying to see if i can find any jQuery plugins available, but couldnt find any.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery UI's [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/); it does exactly what you're looking for (in spite of the poorly chosen name).

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.